# Store passwords safely but determine same passwords

Tags: security, passwords

I have legacy browser game which historicaly uses simple hashing function for password storage. I know that it' far from ideal. However time has proven that most of the cheaters (multiaccounts) use same password for all of fake accounts.

In update of my game I want to store passwords more safely. I already know, that passwords should by randomly salted, hashed by safe algorithms etc. That's all nice.

But is there any way, how to store passwords properly and determine that two (or more) users use same password? I don't want to know the password. I don't want to be able to search by password. I only need to tell, that suspect users A, B and C use same one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you store them correctly - no. This is one of the points of a proper password storage.

You could have very long passwords, beyond what is available on rainbow tables (not sure about the current state of the art, but it used to be 10 or 12 characters) and not salt them. In this case two passwords would have the same hash. **This is a very bad idea** (but a solution nevertheless) - if your passwords leak someone may be able to guess them indirectly ([xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1286/) reference).

You may also look at [homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption), but this is in the realm of science fiction for now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use salt + hashing, you have all the salts as plain text. When a user enters a password, before storing/verifying it, you can hash it with all the salts available and see if you get the corresponding existing hash. :)

The obvious problem with this is that if you are doing it properly with bcrypt or pbkdf2 for hashing, this would be very slow - that's kind of the point in these functions.

I don't think there is any other way you can tell whether two passwords are the same - you need at least one of them plain text, which is only when the user enters it. And then you want to remove it from memory asap, which contradicts doing all these calculations with the plain text password in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This will reduce the security of all passwords somewhat, since it leaks information about when two users have the same password. Even so, it is a workable trade-off and is straightforward to secure within that restriction.

The short answer is: use the same salt for all the passwords, but make that salt unique to your site.

Now the long answer:

First, to describe a standard and appropriate way to handle passwords. I'll get to the differences for you afterwards. (You may know all of this already, but it's worth restating.)

Start with a decent key-stretching algorithm, such as PBKDF2 (there are others, some even better, but PBKDF2 is ubiquitous and sufficient for most uses). Select a number of iterations depending on what is client-side environment is involved. For JavaScript, you'll want something like 1k-4k iterations. For languages with faster math, you can use 10k-100k.

The key stretcher will need a salt. I'll talk about the salt in a moment.

The client sends the password to the server. The server applies a fast hash (SHA-256 is nice) and compares that to the stored hash. (For setting the password, the server does the same thing; it accepts a PBKDF2 hash, applies SHA-256, and then stores it.)

All that is standard stuff. The question is the salt. The best salt is random, but no good for this. The second-best salt is built from service_id+user_id (i.e. use a unique identifier for the service and concatenate the username). Both of these make sure that every user's password hash is unique, even if their passwords are identical. But you don't want that.

So now finally to the core of your question. You want to use a per-service, but not per-user, static salt. So something like "com.example.mygreatapp" (obviously don't use that actual string; use a string based on your app). With a constant salt, all passwords on your service that are the same will stretch (PBKDF2) and hash (SHA256) to the same value and you can compare them without having any idea what the actual password is. But if your password database is stolen, attackers cannot compare the hashes in it to hashes in other sites' databases, even if they use the same algorithm (because they'll have a different salt).

The disadvantage of this scheme is exactly its goal: if two people on your site have the same password and an attacker steals your database and knows the password of one user, they know the password of the other user, too. That's the trade-off.